# How to get correct iframe from Power BI to embed into Angular 8

Tags: angular, powerbi

I am using this code to get Power BI iframe to display report in my angular application. But not getting exact report. Getting a message as "app.powerbi.com refused to connect".

Anyone can please guide as how to create url to get iframe from PowerBi. I have already registered application and grant permissions in AAD azure portal.

```
let embedUrl = POWERBI.BASE_URL + POWERBI.REPORT_ID + "&groupId=" + POWERBI.GROUP_ID;      

let embedReportId = POWERBI.REPORT_ID;  
let config = {  
    type: 'report',  
    accessToken: accessToken,  
    embedUrl: embedUrl,  
    id: embedReportId,  
    settings: {}  
};     
let powerbi = new pbi.service.Service(pbi.factories.hpmFactory, pbi.factories.wpmpFactory, pbi.factories.routerFactory);  
let reportContainer = this.reportContainer.nativeElement;  
powerbi.embed(reportContainer, config);  
let report = powerbi.embed(reportContainer, config);
```

Comment: What is `POWERBI.BASE_URL`?

Comment: https://app.powerbi.com/

Comment: Embed URLs are different (starting with `https://app.powerbi.com/reportEmbed`). You can get it using [Get Report In Group API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/getreportingroup#examples) for example.

Comment: I can get a token from same user, but when I used https://app.powerbi.com/reportEmbed, I get 403

Comment: Do I require any special permission in AAD from admin?

Comment: Yes. Follow [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-sample-for-customers).